# jQuery two column (one dimensional) array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a simple one dimensional array but I want to split the long list into two columns using jQuery. How can I achieve this?

```
var articles = ['article10','article9','article8','article7','article6','article5','article4','article3', 'article2', 'article1'];
for ( var articCounter = articles.length; articCounter > 0; articCounter--) {
    document.write('<a href="../articles/' + articles[articCounter-1] + '.pdf" > ' + articles[articCounter-1] + '</a></br>');  
} // end for
```

I don't want to have to create two different arrays for two different float divs....
I've googled this many times but many other methods deal with multidimensional arrays.

Thank you very much for the help in advance.

EDIT: Right now it's just one long list like so:

Article1
Article2
Article3
....

But I would like to achieve this:
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "two columns"? Provide a sample output so that we exactly know what you are after.

Comment: why dont you just use 2 loops? or a single loop with and if condition on the index to append to two different divs ?

Comment: I see what you're getting at. I could begin to perpend my list to a second div when the counter has reached half the array length. Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but still trying to make it work.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `document.write` to begin with. First because if it's executed after the page has finished loading, it will overwrite the whole page. Secondly because it does not work in an XHTML environment. It's just not good practice for this - there are a very few, specific cases where `document.write` is the best way around, but not here. Also `</br>` is invalid markup in any language. It should be `<br>` in HTML or `<br />` in XML (the white space is optional, and this is also valid in HTML).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, I am of that. I've tried using perpend() but for some reason it was not working. I was sticking to document.write since I'm still a novice and am not largely familiar with the javascript/jQuery library. Do you have suggestions for an alternative to document write?

Comment: Yes, here's an example with [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) iteration and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/): [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/HXarF/1/)

Comment: Edit to previous comment: *Aware of that. 
@FabrícioMatté Thank you, that worked and makes much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will split your array into 2 arrays:

```
var articles = ["article1", "article2", "article3", "article4", "article5", "article6", "article7", "article8", "article9", "article10"];   
var separatorIndex = articles.length & 0x1 ? (articles.length+1)/2 : articles.length/2;

var firstChunk = articles.slice(0,separatorIndex); 
//["article1", "article2", "article3", "article4", "article5"] 
var secondChunk = articles.slice(separatorIndex,articles.length); 
//["article6", "article7", "article8", "article9", "article10"]
```

Then you can use them where and/or how you want.

*Explanation*

The 2nd line finds an *anchor index* (alias -> middle index of division),by which array should be divided into 2 chunks. The array can have `odd` and `even` lengths,and those 2 situations must be distinguished. As it is impossible to divide odd-length array into 2 *equal* parts, it must be divided in such way, that 1st chunk will have 1 element *more* or *less*,than 2nd chunk.Here, I have implemented first case,that is, 1st chunk will have 1 element more,than 2nd one. Here are the examples of different situations:

```
total length | 1st (length) | 2st (length) | separatorIndex 
    10            0-4 (5)        5-9 (5)          5        
    11            0-5 (6)       6-10 (5)          6
    12            0-5 (6)       0-11 (6)          6
```

In table, *`number`-`number`* syntax shows accordingly start and end indexes in array. The division is done by [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function.

Comment: The ternaries and base 16 0x1 is alright, but what's that `&` operator supposed to do?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté `articles.length & 0x1` is binary equivalent of `articles.length%2==1`.

Comment: Where would I add this? before or after my for() loop? Sorry the code is slightly advanced for me.

Comment: @Exklusive Hmm..It's seemed,that you didn't understand my answer. By my code, you will have 2 arrays:`firstChunk` and `secondChunk`. You need to iterate through each one, and make your DOM Manipulations( adding element into appropriate column(maybe it is `div`, maybe `table` element). Does it make sense now?

Comment: @Engineer Ah, yes it worked. Wasn't completely sure but I thought I knew what you meant. I tried it out anyway, it took me a while but I got it. Thanks. For me, the articles printed out in reverse order so I tried taking out .reverse() and it worked splendidly. I think that was because I originally typed the articles in the array in reverse order.  You don't have to but it would be great if you could explain your code a little bit as well (e.g. the grammar of the first line and how the slice() works). Many thanks again!

Comment: @Exklusive I have updated my answer. One more note,if you want to know how `.slice()` works, look into docs I have provided in my answer.